X11 Forwarding works but running the program locally causes it to crash
I'm facing an issue where I can successfully run a program remotely using SSH with X11 forwarding, but when I try to launch the same program directly on the target machine, it crashes with an error related to missing .so files.
Here are the details of target machine:

Jetson Xavier NX
Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
aarch64

I checked LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PATH but nothing help.
However, the program was working fine earlier, and this issue just started recently.
Could anyone explain why this happens?
What might be different between running the program locally and using X11 Forwarding, and how can I fix this issue?
Thanks for your help!

Ubuntu 18.04 became EOL in 2023 and is thus off topic here

You can ask this on [unix.se] instead, but if you do, make sure to show the actual errors you are getting. Nobody can help if we don't know what the error is.

Thank you for your responses. I have temporarily resolved the issue using LD_DEBUG, but I am still curious about what conditions could cause differences in linker's behavior between remote and local executions, even when using the same user and with identical LD_LIBRARY_PATH settings.
